# How to retrieve lastLogin using Smartsheet API and c#

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api

I am attempting to pull all user's lastLogin from Smartsheet using c# and the SS API.  The values come back null.  I posted this on Smartsheet Community and someone indicated that I need to add include=lastLogin to my code.  I have reviewed the Smartsheet API code and searched through the web for syntax on this, but have had no luck.  When in C# and I use .ListUsers, the help syntax indicates it only accepts 2 arguments (email, paging), which is all I can find anywhere, too.  Any help is appreciated...thanks.

Smartsheet API code examples: https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#list-users

Simplified code that returns null for all lastLogins:

```
PaginatedResult<User> usersX = smartsheet.UserResources.ListUsers(null, new PaginationParameters(true, null, null));

foreach (User tmpUser in usersX.Data)
{ Console.WriteLine(tmpUser.LastLogin); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The LastLogin will be included only if :

```
the request is submitted by a system administrator, and
the returned IndexResult object that contains a maximum of 100 User objects.
```

Maybe you're using a regular smartsheet acocunt and not a system admin one.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response.  I am a System Admin.  Does anyone know what the syntax would be for retrieving Last Login?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you ever got an answer to this, but for others looking for a solution: There is an overload to the ListUsers method that takes a list of response `includes` with the only currently supported value being `LAST_LOGIN`:

```
            PaginatedResult<User> usersX = smartsheet.UserResources.ListUsers(null, 
                new List<ListUserInclusion> { ListUserInclusion.LAST_LOGIN },
                new PaginationParameters(true, null, null));

            foreach (User tmpUser in usersX.Data)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(tmpUser.LastLogin); 
            }
```